# Lose state in onChange function in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import JSONEditor from "jsoneditor";
import "jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.css";

const JSONReact = ({ json, setValid, onChange }) => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const props = {
      onChangeText: (value) => {
        // console.log(value, 'vv')
        onChange(value);
      },
      onValidationError: (e) => {
        setValid(Boolean(!e.length));
      },
      modes: ["code"]
    };
    ref1.current = new JSONEditor(ref2.current, props);

    if (json) {
      ref1.current.set(json);
    }

    return () => {
      ref1.current.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref2} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('{"cars": "22w-08w-23"}');
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);
  const onChange = (j) => {
    console.log(valid);
    // setState(j);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JSONReact
        mode="code"
        onChange={onChange}
        json={JSON.parse(state)}
        setValid={setValid}
      />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need the updated value regarding error here `console.log(valid);`, but it does not update inside onChange function. 
 Question: What is the issue and how to solve it?
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-khorana-pdem1l?file=/src/App.js:0-1233

Comment: how do you know that it does not update, you are not using it anywere

Comment: @henk, i check in onChange function. I need that state there. Could you help?

Comment: @ChrisG, i can not use it in useEffect because i need onChange function .Do you know a solution?

Comment: @Asking didn't understand what is the issue. If you `console.log(j)` you can see updated value inside your `onChange` function

Comment: try to explain what is the final goal.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, i need console.log(valid); , i need valid state to updated there, because i need to do some manipulations in that function using valid. Could you help?

Comment: @henk, i need `console.log(valid);` inside that function, because i need to do some manipulations in that function using `valid`. Could you help?

Comment: @henk, try to add inside a invalid json and there will appear a error in console.log but i can not see that error inside the onChange function.

Comment: I see what the problem with `valid ` is, but I don't see how to help you get it inside of onChange. Since that is a closure issue here, I think you have to saddle the horse from the other side. But for that I need to know exactly what you are trying to achieve. E.g. if you are trying to call an api, do it directly from ´onValidationError´

Comment: maybe you should try the react wrapper of json-editor https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoneditor-react

Comment: @henk, i need when the json is valid to  make `// setState(j);`, when is invalid No. This is my goal